# Woocommerce - capture output from shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a shortcode setup using the Shortcoder plugin. It returns some text that I've defined (which will be changed on a weekly basis).

I'm trying to simplify weekly changes as much as possible for my client.

Using this shortcode is great - because I can put the same text anywhere on the site, and it will automatically update when I update the content of that shortcode.

However, I'm trying to get it to work within a WooCommerce email - which doesn't work, because it's obviously off the site so can't 'translate' the shortcode.

Is there any way that I could either:

a) Make the email template take the value of the shortcode and output it in the HTML email
b) When a customer places their order, WooCommerce takes the value of the shortcode and inputs this into the DB, so I can then call this in the email?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how you're generating the email in the first place but maybe you'd want to use the [apply_shortcodes()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_shortcodes/) function to get the output of your shortcode (eg. `$my_shortcode_contents = apply_shortcodes('[my_shortcode]');`) and then pass it to the email somehow?

Comment: Thanks @cabrerahector - I'm generating the email using WooCommerce. It's the Processing Order email. I'm just amending the PHP template.

Comment: Got it. Then what I suggested earlier will probably get you on the right track :)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to sort this. Popping it here in case it helps someone in the future.

```
   $collection  = do_shortcode( '[sc name="collection"]' );
   <p>Your order collection date is <?php echo $collection; ?>.</p>
```